# Correct way to modify maven plugin configuration from mojo

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I know this is subjective question and it will be closed most probably. But I don't know where to ask this question to get answer.

There is one small annoying thing with maven android plugin - it modifies original manifest file and if you are running maven in working folder your vcs is proposing you to commit these changes.

Example: we have several environments to run if I build build with beta environment it will modify app name in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

This is could be easily solved by copying original manifest and give reference to the copy to the android maven plugin. But I've decided to make it's more easy for developer so plugin will do this automatically except situation when developer specifies that he wants this update to be done under original manifest.

It was easy to modify functionality (copy file and replace property that keeps reference to the File) but the problem is that I need to pass this property to other mojos.

The property defined in abstract mojo `AbstractAndroidMojo` which doesn't have `execute` method. And all other mojos extend this class. The definition look like this:

```
/**
 * The <code>AndroidManifest.xml</code> file.
 *
 * @parameter default-value="${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
 */
protected File androidManifestFile;
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061386/maven-how-to-pass-parameters-between-mojos):

```
private void updatePluginConfiguration ( String newManifestFileValue )
{
    for ( Plugin plugin : project.getBuild().getPlugins() )
    {
        if ( plugin.getArtifactId().equals( "android-maven-plugin" ) )
        {
            Xpp3Dom configuration = (Xpp3Dom) plugin.getConfiguration();
            Xpp3Dom manifestFileParameter = configuration.getChild( "androidManifestFile" );
            if ( manifestFileParameter == null )
            {
                manifestFileParameter = new Xpp3Dom( "androidManifestFile" );
                configuration.addChild( manifestFileParameter );
            }
            manifestFileParameter.setValue( newManifestFileValue );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. There are many explicit ways to make it working but all of them will require to change all current mojos.

I wonder if someone knows why the answer doesn't work or how to make it working.

The code of updated plugin could be found here:
https://github.com/emartynov/maven-android-plugin/tree/keep-android-manifest

Thanks for everyone who read till the end.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your goal within the same lifecycle phase? If not, in the post you provided it's written:

> Note: Any configuration changes are discarded at the end of the current phase.

The other thing to consider: are the goals run in order you expect? Have a look at this post: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-plugin-execution-order-in-same-phase/ - Perhaps it's the ordering of plugins that you're having problems with.

Other thing to consider: perhaps you'd prefer a cleaner solution - to add such feature to the android-maven-plugin? Manfred Moser is usually open to proposals backed by pull requests ;)

I'll be most propably doing the very same thing in my plugin. The only difference is that I'm reusing goals from maven-dependency-plugin to copy dependencies within my custom plugin lifecycle. I'm trying to make a plugin for InstallShield projects building.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I already stopped idea to make this working

Comment: OK, need to clear things up. I've tried using the same solution and failed - configuration is added within the MavenProject instance, but it seems that even though the running order is proper, it is not added to Mojo as if it was instantiated earlier. I'm going to use maven-executor project, but will try to look at MavenSession and BuildPluginManager first