# How to use entire plugin configuration in Maven Mojo

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to build a Maven plugin that uses a Spring Boot application internally.

Now, I'd like to make the Spring Boot app configurable using a `<configuration>` tag in the `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <my-maven-plugin.key1>value1</my-maven-plugin.key1>
        <my-maven-plugin.key2>value2</my-maven-plugin.key2>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

These properties can be injected into a Mojo using the `@Parameter` annotation.

```
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.SITE)
public class GenerateMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(name = "my-maven-plugin.key1", readonly = true)
    private String key1;

    @Parameter(name = "my-maven-plugin.key2", readonly = true)
    private String key2;

    @Override
    public void execute() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("my-maven-plugin.key1", key1);
        props.setProperty("my-maven-plugin.key2", key2);

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(GenerateApp.class)
                .web(false)
                .bannerMode(OFF)
                .logStartupInfo(false)
                .properties(props)
                .run();
    }
}
```

A `Properties` object is being created that can be used in Spring. But I'd like to avoid building the `Properties` on my own.

While I could rearrange the `<configuration>` like this

```
<configuration>
    <my-maven-plugin>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    </my-maven-plugin>
</configuration>
```

and inject all properties like so

```
@Parameter(name = "my-maven-plugin", readonly = true)
private Properties myProperties;
```

I'd prefer not having to wrap all my properties in another tag as this feels more natural in a Maven plugin.

Is there a way to inject the entire configuration in a single `Properties` object in Maven without wrapping properties in another tag? A `Map<String, Object>` or similar would also be fine for me.

Comment: Why are you trying to integrate Spring Boot in a Maven Plugin? For what purpose? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Plexus documentation is rather confusing to me and I don't want to unravel the mess with Sisu/Guice. I am building a command line app for building a static website/blog and as I work with Spring (Boot) 90% of my time, that's just the most efficient way to go for me. I am trying to build it without dependency on any build tool and rather just write thin adapters that turn it into a Maven or Gradle plugin.

Comment: Using spring boot parent and some dependencies isn't thin enough?

Comment: I see your point. Probably using Maven Exec Plugin would be enough to use the standalone Spring Boot app in my Maven lifecycle. I'll take this into consideration. Thanks for questioning my plan. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straight forward way to do what you ask about. However, you may try the following alternatives.

1) You could use project properties:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value1</key2>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

2) There is a couple of ways to access mojo configuration in runtime: see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125389/best-way-to-access-the-runtime-configuration-of-a-maven-plugin-from-a-custom-moj).

3) *This is more like an idea, not actually an answer*: you could look at how `@Parameter` annotation works and add code to your plugin which would use same annotations and populate a `Map` or `Properties` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll play with your suggested approaches. Especially alternative 2) and 3) look promising.